# Empty vocabulary for single letter by CountVectorizer

Tags: python, nlp, vectorization, feature-extraction, countvectorizer

Trying to convert string into numeric vector,

```
### Clean the string
def names_to_words(names):
    print('a')
    words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ",names).lower().split()
    print('b')

    return words


### Vectorization
def Vectorizer():
    Vectorizer= CountVectorizer(
                analyzer = "word",  
                tokenizer = None,  
                preprocessor = None, 
                stop_words = None,  
                max_features = 5000)
    return Vectorizer  


### Test a string
s = 'abc...'
r = names_to_words(s)
feature = Vectorizer().fit_transform(r).toarray()
```

But when I encoutered:

```
 ['g', 'o', 'm', 'd']
```

There's error:

```
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

It seems there's a problem with such single-letter string.
what should I do？
Thx

Comment: So what do you want to do? Include these single letter words in your vocabulary?

Answer (score 14):

The default token_pattern regexp in CountVectorizer selects words which have atleast 2 chars as [stated in documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> **token_pattern : string**
>
> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if
> analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more
> alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always
> treated as a token separator).

From the [source code of CountVectorizer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L660) it is `r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b`

Change it to `r"(?u)\b\w+\b` to include 1 letter words.

Change your code to the following (include the `token_pattern` parameter with above suggestion):

```
Vectorizer= CountVectorizer(
                analyzer = "word",  
                tokenizer = None,  
                preprocessor = None, 
                stop_words = None,  
                max_features = 5000,
                token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
```

Comment: Why would it implicitly set this condition of "2 or more characters"? This just bit me today and I'm glad I found your answer. Very helpful!